# Can't figure out why the selection buttons will not show for my radio buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on a project using React.js. I am currently working on the part of the app where the user gets asked questions and selects the bubbles of the radio buttons to answer the questions, this is used to get a better understanding of the unsers goal. My problem is when an answer is selected for the questions, the bubble will not fill in (or turn color in other words) when selected. But if you were to go through and select an answer for each question and click submit, the answers will be shown in the console, showing that they have been properly selected.

Test Case:
Create a list of questions that can be properly selected for the customer.

Step 1) Look and read the questions and select the answer that suits the user.
Expectation: As a person is going through the questions and selecting answers. The answer bubble will show that the answer has been selected.
ACTUAL: The answer bubble will NOT show that an answer has been selected.

Step 2) After all questions are answered, the user will hit the submit button to submit their answers.
EXPECTATION: When submit button is selected the users answers will be logged to the console.
ACTUAL: When submit button is selected the users answers will be logged to the console.

No errors are shown in the console during this process.

I have tried looking up different ways of using bootstrap to fix the issue, and have used the React.js documentation to see if there was something I missed but i have had no luck.

Here is my code:

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />)
```

```css
import React from 'react';
import Introduction from './components/introduction';
import Questions from './components/beginning';
import Male from './components/questions';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';

 export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path= "/" element={<Introduction />} />
        <Route path="/beginning" element= {<Questions />} />
        <Route path="/questions" element= {<Male />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

```html
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

export default function Questions() {
    const[formData, setFormData] = useState(
        {gender: "", userAge: "", goals:"", motivate: ""})

    function handleChange(event){
        const{name, value, type, checked} = event.target
       setFormData(prevFormData => {
        return {
            ...prevFormData,
            [name]: type === 'checkbox' ? checked : value 
        }
       })
    }

    function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log(formData)
       }

    return (
        <>
        <header>Questions</header>

<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

    <fieldset>
    <legend>What was your gender at birth</legend>
        <input 
        type='radio'
        id = 'male'
        name = 'gender' 
        value = 'male'
        checked={formData.male === "male"}
        onChange={handleChange}/>
        <label htmlFor="male"> Male </label>
                <br />

        <input 
        type='radio'
        id='female'
        name='gender'
        value = 'female' 
        checked={formData.female === "female"}
        onChange={handleChange}/>
        <label htmlFor="female"> Female </label>
                <br />
    </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>How old are you?</legend>

                <input 
                type='radio'
                id="young"
                name="userAge"
                value="young"
                checked={formData.young === "young"}
                onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="young"> 18-28 </label>
                <br />

                <input 
                type='radio'
                id="middleAged"
                name="userAge"
                value="middleAged"
                checked={formData.middleAged === "middleAged"}
                onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="middleAged"> 29-39 </label>
                <br />

                <input 
                type='radio'
                id="older"
                name="userAge"
                value="older"
                checked={formData.older === "older"}
                onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="older"> 40-50 </label>
                <br />

                <input 
                type='radio'
                id="senior"
                name="userAge"
                value="senior"
                checked={formData.senior === "senior"}
                onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="senior"> 51+ </label>
                <br />
            </fieldset>
            <br />

            <fieldset>
                <legend>What kind of fitness would you prefer?</legend>

                <input 
                type="radio"
                id="active"
                name="goals"
                value="active"
                checked = {formData.active === "active"}
                onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor='active'>To stay active!</label>
                <br />

                <input
                type="radio"
                id="weight"
                name="goals"
                value= "weight"
                checked = {formData.weight === "weight"}
                onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="weight"> To loose weight</label>
            </fieldset>
            <br />

            <fieldset>
                <legend>What would help motivate you when exercising?</legend>

                <input 
                type ="radio"
                id="music"
                name = "motivate"
                value="music"
                checked = {formData.music === 'music'}
                onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor = "music"> Music</label>
                <br />

                <input
                type ="radio"
                id="speeches"
                name ="motivate"
                value ="speeches"
                checked = {formData.speeches === "speeches"}
                onChange = {handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor = "speeches">Motivational speeches</label>
                <br />

                <input
                type = "radio"
                id="videos"
                name ="motivate"
                value ="videos"
                checked ={formData.videos === "videos"}
                onChange = {handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor = "videos"> Success Videos</label>
            </fieldset>
            <br />
            <br />
            <button>Submit</button>
            </Form>


        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `checked` prop on all of your radio inputs, you are testing for equality against an object key that does not exist inside `formData`.

For example, `checked={formData.young === "young"}`.
Here the value of`formData.young` will always be `undefined`, so `checked` will always be `false`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Questions() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    gender: "",
    userAge: "",
    goals: "",
    motivate: ""
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value, type, checked } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => {
      return {
        ...prevFormData,
        [name]: type === "checkbox" ? checked : value
      };
    });
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(formData);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <header>Questions</header>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>What was your gender at birth</legend>
          <input
            type="radio"
            id="male"
            name="gender"
            value="male"
            checked={formData.gender === "male"}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="male"> Male </label>
          <br />

          <input
            type="radio"
            id="female"
            name="gender"
            value="female"
            checked={formData.gender === "female"}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="female"> Female </label>
          <br />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>How old are you?</legend>

          <input
            type="radio"
            id="young"
            name="userAge"
            value="young"
            checked={formData.userAge === "young"}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="young"> 18-28 </label>
          <br />

          <input
            type="radio"
            id="middleAged"
            name="userAge"
            value="middleAged"
            checked={formData.userAge === "middleAged"}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="middleAged"> 29-39 </label>
          <br />

          <input
            type="radio"
            id="older"
            name="userAge"
            value="older"
            checked={formData.userAge === "older"}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="older"> 40-50 </label>
          <br />

          <input
            type="radio"
            id="senior"
            name="userAge"
            value="senior"
            checked={formData.userAge === "senior"}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="senior"> 51+ </label>
          <br />
        </fieldset>
        <br />

        <fieldset>
          <legend>What kind of fitness would you prefer?</legend>

          <input
            type="radio"
            id="active"
            name="goals"
            value="active"
            checked={formData.goals === "active"}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="active">To stay active!</label>
          <br />

          <input
            type="radio"
            id="weight"
            name="goals"
            value="weight"
            checked={formData.goals === "weight"}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="weight"> To loose weight</label>
        </fieldset>
        <br />

        <fieldset>
          <legend>What would help motivate you when exercising?</legend>

          <input
            type="radio"
            id="music"
            name="motivate"
            value="music"
            checked={formData.motivate === "music"}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="music"> Music</label>
          <br />

          <input
            type="radio"
            id="speeches"
            name="motivate"
            value="speeches"
            checked={formData.motivate === "speeches"}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="speeches">Motivational speeches</label>
          <br />

          <input
            type="radio"
            id="videos"
            name="motivate"
            value="videos"
            checked={formData.motivate === "videos"}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="videos"> Success Videos</label>
        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <br />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit condescending-murdock-bn6u5y]